Static Route Windows issue
I would like some help and thank you for taking the time to read my question.
As far as I know, Windows routing has route preference following this rule:
1 - More specific route, i.e. smaller or directly connected subnet network.
2 - to break ties between equal routes, use the metric to define which path.
If I'm wrong, you can correct me.
On the work network, some use a Checkpoint VPN (Remote Access) client for a routine and it was configured with an extremely large route: 10.0.0.0/9.
With this very large subnet, it ends up taking over my network's subnet and consequently stops accessing internal resources.
Side note: I don't have administration over the VPN client, I don't have access to talk to someone in IT who administers it to request a fix.
The issue of the problem comes in here. This VPN, when connected, configures route 10.0.0.0/9 with metric 1 in routing. If I change the metric to 100 and create a new static for my network as 1, nothing resolves it.
It bypasses the Windows route table and sends this entire subnet to VPN.
All traffic is not sent to the VPN, only the 10.0.0.0/9 subnet.
In short.
My network: 10.1.0.0/24, 10.1.1.0/24
VPN Network: 10.0.0.0/9
Route created and metrics specified:
0.0.0.0/0 via gateway 10.1.0.1 metric 1
10.1.1.0/24 via gateway 10.1.0.1 metric 1
10.0.0.0/9 via gateway 10.139.38.1 metric 100
Is there something I'm missing here?
Any checkpoint enforcement via software?
Any ideas on how to make this communication work?

I think you need to push those routes and test from the VPN device that pushes the routes to the clients when they connect. Depending on the configuration of your VPN, overriding these routes on connected clients can mess things up. I would tackle from the VPN configuration side if it were me. If it's business critical, you should have vendor support, so it may take a call if you do not have access and access is entirely lost to see what options are available to get current configs from physical device, wipe, reset password, pushed backed up configs, then make your changes and test accordingly
